# JDBC test suite

Tags: java, testing, jdbc

Is there any test suite available to validate a new JDBC driver implementation ?

Something that would test if an implementation respects the JDBC default standards. Hopefully with some degree of compatibility like with the optional support of ROWID.

I've seen Oracle has such a JDBC API test suite, but I can't seem to find the download link.

Note: I dont need the api test suite exclusively, although this could be a solution, but any other good JDBC impl testing suite would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the 1.3.1 test suite [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-141179.html).

Looking at the date it seems to be pretty outdated and for current versions they only supply specification and the api itself.

Comment: This link is the same I put in duffymo's comment which leads to the deprecated page.  Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Hmm. You are right. http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221 is the latest JCR. It states "This RI and TCK for this JSR will be delivered as part of RI and TCK for Java SE 6 (JSR 270), respectively. The proposed Java SE 6 licensing terms are available here: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=270. ". The 1.3.1 is outdated anyways. And I doubt that the vendor dependent Oracle "ROWID" is part of the official API. You have to check where you can get the general "TCK".

Comment: Ok then, thanks for the help and information, I'll stick to the RI and TCK then I'll write my own batch of tests.